# Add array of objects with the dot notation

Tags: laravel, multidimensional-array

With the following code `Arr::set($array, 'messages.to.email', $value);`

That will generate an output like:

```
{
  "messages": {
    "subject": "this is out email",
    "to": {
       "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that I need this output instead:

```
{
  "messages": [{
    "subject": "this is out email",
    "to": {
       "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
    }
  }]
}
```

Being messages an array of objects. I haven't been able to find a native way of doing it, so I'm thinking of manually adding something like `messages[].to.email`

Am I missing something? A magic helper or syntax? to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: did you try with an index? `messages.0.to.email`

Comment: I did not, I tried messages[0].to.email tho. Let me check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used an index for the messages it would force it to be an array:

```
Arr::set($array, 'messages.0.to.email', $value);
```

This is just adding another level/container to this by specificying that there is something between 'messages' and 'to'. Could be named anything, but `0` is for zero indexed array here, which would be an array in JSON not an object.